# rails server cannot run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new at Ruby on rails. when I run **rails server** on terminal, I got the error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I had researched and tried some solutions with the same problem of other people. But didn't found the way to fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to just run hello world?

Comment: I following the tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: So, you are running server without an app? Cause i don't see any code.

Comment: but when run **rails server** I got the error as above.

Comment: **rails new blog** for the new app

Comment: and then **cd blog** then **rails server** to start server. Finally I got this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `bundle install` in console, before running server. Or maybe you haven't installed `bundle` gem, so you need `gem install bundle`.

Though, it should install gems by the guide. Perhaps problem with rvm.

Comment: **bundle install** is help me.Thanks.